# Open neutral issue

Tags: wiring

I have an open neutral and no lights. There are 2 lights and 2 plugs on this circuit. I did not do any work to the shed.  I changed both outlets. What else could cause this problem?

Comment: How is power supplied to the shed?  Also, how did you diagnose  open neutral?

Comment: What feeds the shed, and what makes you believe there's an open neutral? Is the rest of the service fine?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more info before we can help you; please edit it into your question. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: There is a direct line through attic that runs into the shed.  I tested it with a tester that showed open neutral. I also tested with a meter. 96 volts at each outlet.

Comment: When you changed the outlets one of those could be feeding the lights and pulled the neutral loose or if using backstabs made a bad connection

Comment: I triple checked all connections. But I had an open neutral before I changed the outlets. I had not done any work to that circuit since I bought the place 3 years ago.